# Json object successfully filled with xmlhttprequest suddenly is "null"

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

```
function getOptionsData()
{
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        json_options = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getData.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

"json_options" is a global variable, which should get filled with the responseText of the XMLHttpRequest, which is containing a valid json String:

```
[{"id":"3","model":"NZ\/","model1":"","tablenr":"1","tabkey":"SSG\/","length":"4","descript":"Schukostecker gerade","matchcode":"","price":"0","pricex":"0","code":"1","textnr":"0","artikelnr":"0","funktion":"Seite 1"},{"id":"4","model":"NZ\/","model1":"","tablenr":"1","tabkey":"SWS\/","length":"4","descript":"Schuko gewinkelt \/ angled 90 Grad","matchcode":"","price":"0","pricex":"0","code":"1","textnr":"0","artikelnr":"0","funktion":"Seite 1"}]
```

At this point everything is fine and json_options contains a valid json Object.

The function "getOptionsData" gets called in the function "createOptionsTable":

```
function createOptionsTable()
{
getOptionsData();
var element = null;

for(var i = 0; i < json_options.length; i++)
{
[...]
```

When i want to access "json_options" at this point, it says that it is null and i dont have any idea why.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the code after `getOptionsData();` is executed before the call's success callback. so u get `json_options` as null

Try like this

```
   function getOptionsData(callback)
   {
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
           json_options = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           callback();

        }
     }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "getData.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }


 function createOptionsTable()
 {
   var callback = function()
   {
        var element = null;
        for(var i = 0; i < json_options.length; i++)
        {
          [...]
         }
   }

   getOptionsData(callback);
}
```

Comment: Great! exactly what i was searching for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getOptionsData()
{
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        json_options = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         for(var i = 0; i < json_options.length; i++)
        {
          [...]
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getData.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Your `for loop` should execute after you could actually get the reponse from ajax and not inside `createOptionsTable()`...